# Roku: How to change Poster-Grid Captions Font size

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Bright script using scene graph. i want to change size of default font without Font node. I used "SmallestBoldSystemFont" font. It appears large font then actual require size.

```
  <PosterGrid 
  id = "example"   
  basePosterSize="[150,150]"
  itemSpacing="[27,27]"
  caption1NumLines="2"
  caption1Font = "font:SmallestBoldSystemFont"
  numColumns="10"
  numRows="1" />
```

Comment: Actually, I understand what you are doing pls explain.

Comment: I want change the caption1Font font size..ex -m.caption1Font.font.size = 15

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [in docs](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/postergrid.md#fields) *caption1Font* field accept **Font object**, so you have to create an object and just set the role for that font:

```
    <PosterGrid
        id = "example"
        basePosterSize="[150,150]"
        itemSpacing="[27,27]"
        caption1NumLines="2"
        numColumns="10"
        numRows="1">
        <Font role="caption1Font" size="15" uri="font:SmallestBoldSystemFont"/>
    </PosterGrid>
```

Comment: It can also be done in Brightscript.. example.caption1Font.font.size = 13

Comment: Sounds strange, could you please provide some code, where you set your font?

Comment: m.caption1Font = m.top.findNode("caption1Font")   ,    m.caption1Font.font.size = 15

Comment: If you want to change your font size in brs file, you have to do smth like that:
m.example = m.top.findNode("example") ("example" is id of your PosterGrid.)

m.example.caption1Font.size  = 15, as described in 1st comment, or just copy code i posted above.

Comment: hii @hornyhedgehog One Question in my mind. Which Font use Roku as a ByDefault?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Font](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/typographic-nodes/font.md) Node. you can change any component Font Like Below.

**First Scenario :**

Here you can download ttf file from google and add it in your application. Here change Size in Pixel Wise.

```
<Label>
  <Font role = "font" uri = "pkg:/fonts/font.ttf" size = "24" />
</Label>
```

**Second Scenario:**

You Can Change Font write inside a Component Like below. Here Different [Size](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/typographic-nodes/font.md) Provide By Roku documentation.

```
<Label id = "test"
  font = "font:MediumBoldSystemFont" 
  />
```